# Managing large $.ajax POST requests to PHP to insert JSON data into a mySQL table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to write a large amount of data (500MB JSON array) to a mySQL database. I've decided to chop that array into smaller chunks (as 2MB JSON arrays) and pushed them into `jsonarr` (2MB JSON arrays) so that the PHP/mySQL machine only has to process 2MB at a time.  But...

The way my code is set up just requests `jsonarr.length` `insertData.php` files asynchronously, causing a server-side memory problem after about 40 requests resulting in a console error message of `POST http://myurl.com/path/insertData.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` (or `::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` or after a while `::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED`). How do I listen for a successful server response and then POST the next `jsonarr[i]` in JavaScript?

**JavaScript**

```
var jsonarr = [json1,json2,json3]; // array of JSON objects
for (var i in jsonarr) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "insertData.php",
        data: { djson: JSON.stringify({ json: jsonarr[i] }) }, // jsonarr[i]
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP** (example for one key.  *Note:* I'm new to PHP)

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$arr = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
$items = $arr['json'];
$length = sizeof($items);

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    $keyName = $items[$i]['keyName'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO obs (keyName) VALUES ('$keyName')";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

I know I can append a statement like this at the end of my PHP code:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "done";
}
```

But I can't get `console.log(data)` in my JS to print "done" to the console, and I'm not sure how to listen for that response even if it did work.

I tried to increase my settings for memory usage under `php.ini` in my cPanel root directory but that didn't help.

Is there a better way to do this?  I do need to use JavaScript, so unfortunately a direct import is not an option for me.

Comment: you're doing async requests. if the ordering of those chunks is relevant, then you can/will corrupt it,b ecause the order they reach the server is entirely up to the network gods to determine. as well, each ajax request is completely independent of each other. you'll get 1 php script execution for every chunk you send, and each execution will be independent of all the others. you won't get one big chunk in the db, you'll get 250 separate chunks in any order they feel like being in.

Comment: @MarcB I just need them in the server, I don't care about the order whatsoever.